# Hadoop compression headers and footers

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, compression

Gzip compressed file format is known to be a DEFLATE compressed file format  with extra headers and a footer. Similar is the case with lzop codec which is LZO format with extra headers.

Any idea what these headers and footers are? How can I see their contents?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gzip header and trailer format is defined in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That was quite informative. Upon referring the link, i've got a few more questions. (1) Does Gzipped file have footer by any chance? (2) Does the header [and footer(if any)] member-names such as ID1, ID2, etc., remain common across different compression formats and only their respective values differ? My 2nd question would help to understand LZOP.

Comment: You must not have fully read the RFC. It describes both the header and the trailer (footer). Read the RFC. Also noted in the RFC that you did not read is the fact the the gzip format is only used for one compressed format, deflate. You do not wrap LZO data with it.

Comment: My comments probably were not very clear. In fact i went through the RFC and could not find any (named) footer/trailer.  Whereas in the case of headers there are named members such as ID1, ID2.  I just wanted to know if the headers discussed in the RFC are also applicable to other compression formats too, considering them as "generalized headers". Thanks for that quick response.

Comment: The trailer is shown clearly after the "compressed blocks".

Comment: Ok. That should be CRC32 and ISIZE.  Any inputs on lzop?

Comment: Please read my first comment above. lzop does not use the gzip wrapper format.